# Kendo UI filtering doesn't work on Dates

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, filtering, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using Kendo UI and I am trying to use the filter property in the grid with the following code

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("TaskListGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
        columns.Bound(p => p.InstrumentType.DisplayName).Title("Instrument Type");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CounterParty).Title("Counterparty");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CommodityType);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ContractDate).Format(Settings.Current.DatePattern);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Price);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Currency);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Comment);
        columns.Template(@<text>
@Html.ActionLink("View details", "Index", item.InstrumentType.DetailController(), new {      Id = item.ContractId }, null)
</text>).Width(120);
     })
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
```

When I execute this code in my localSTS the filtering works fine on ContractDate(DateTime without the time component). But when I deploy the same code without making any changes, In the deployed environment filtering doesn't work properly for the ContractDate, Could someone help me with this

Comment: You have to give us more info. What is the Settings.Current.DatePattern? Is it fixed string or something like CultureInfo.CurrentCulture? Is time is always set to 0:00 at your deployed environment?

Comment: Hi, DatePattern is to format the date so that it displays only the date component and you are right about the time component, it is not always set to 0:00 and hence I am not able to filter since filtering takes into account the time component, Is there any way to ignore the time component?

Comment: I have tried using ContractDate=ContractDate.Date there by taking only the Date component, but even that doesnt seem to be working, Is there any other way to ignore the Time component here, please help